# Override folder functionality and conflicts?

Tags: php, inheritance, overriding, prestashop, prestashop-1.5

Override folder functionality and conflicts?

I have a class file called `group.php` in the prestashop base code. 
I want to add a new field and make some functional changes to that `group.php` file.

I have created a custom module and did those changes there. When i install that module, my inherited `group.php` file is sent to the Base Override folder and stays there.

Now my question is,

**How that override functionality is working?**

**How the conflicts are managed by prestashop?**

For eg: I have 2 modules which are seperately overriding the same file `group.php`. 
If i install those 2 module simultaneously which `group.php` will be there in the base override folder?

Comment: Hi Kirubanidhi, do you need any more informations on the subject? If I answered your concerns correctly, won't you mind accepting my answer to close this thread?

Answer (score 3):

Here is the `addOverride()` method from `Module` class:

```
/**
 * Add all methods in a module override to the override class
 *
 * @param string $classname
 * @return bool
 */
public function addOverride($classname)
{
    $path = Autoload::getInstance()->getClassPath($classname.'Core');

    // Check if there is already an override file, if not, we just need to copy the file
    if (!($classpath = Autoload::getInstance()->getClassPath($classname)))
    {
        $override_src = $this->getLocalPath().'override'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$path;
        $override_dest = _PS_ROOT_DIR_.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'override'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$path;
        if (!is_writable(dirname($override_dest)))
            throw new Exception(sprintf(Tools::displayError('directory (%s) not writable'), dirname($override_dest)));
        copy($override_src, $override_dest);
        // Re-generate the class index
        Autoload::getInstance()->generateIndex();
        return true;
    }

    // Check if override file is writable
    $override_path = _PS_ROOT_DIR_.'/'.Autoload::getInstance()->getClassPath($classname);
    if ((!file_exists($override_path) && !is_writable(dirname($override_path))) || (file_exists($override_path) && !is_writable($override_path)))
        throw new Exception(sprintf(Tools::displayError('file (%s) not writable'), $override_path));

    // Make a reflection of the override class and the module override class
    $override_file = file($override_path);
    eval(preg_replace(array('#^\s*<\?php#', '#class\s+'.$classname.'\s+extends\s+([a-z0-9_]+)(\s+implements\s+([a-z0-9_]+))?#i'), array('', 'class '.$classname.'OverrideOriginal'), implode('', $override_file)));
    $override_class = new ReflectionClass($classname.'OverrideOriginal');

    $module_file = file($this->getLocalPath().'override'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$path);
    eval(preg_replace(array('#^\s*<\?php#', '#class\s+'.$classname.'(\s+extends\s+([a-z0-9_]+)(\s+implements\s+([a-z0-9_]+))?)?#i'), array('', 'class '.$classname.'Override'), implode('', $module_file)));
    $module_class = new ReflectionClass($classname.'Override');

    // Check if none of the methods already exists in the override class
    foreach ($module_class->getMethods() as $method)
        if ($override_class->hasMethod($method->getName()))
            throw new Exception(sprintf(Tools::displayError('The method %1$s in the class %2$s is already overriden.'), $method->getName(), $classname));

    // Check if none of the properties already exists in the override class
    foreach ($module_class->getProperties() as $property)
        if ($override_class->hasProperty($property->getName()))
            throw new Exception(sprintf(Tools::displayError('The property %1$s in the class %2$s is already defined.'), $property->getName(), $classname));

    // Insert the methods from module override in override
    $copy_from = array_slice($module_file, $module_class->getStartLine() + 1, $module_class->getEndLine() - $module_class->getStartLine() - 2);
    array_splice($override_file, $override_class->getEndLine() - 1, 0, $copy_from);
    $code = implode('', $override_file);
    file_put_contents($override_path, $code);

    return true;
}
```

As stated in the comments conflicts are handle at method and properties scale.

If you try to install a module that override a new method or a new property, everything will work fine and the two files will be combined.

If you try to install a module that override a method already overridden by a different module the installation will fail.

Answer (score 2):

When two modules are overriding the same file then PrestaShop adds a comment at the top of overridden function(s) to identify which function in overridden by which module.

Example of that comment is:

```
/*
* module: supercheckout
* date: 2016-12-01 08:03:28
* version: 1.0.1
*/
public function overriddenFunction()
{
    parent::mylogout();
    -- Custom Code Here --
}
```

You can check this in the overridden file on your end (/override/classes/group.php) in your case.

The overridden code is then remove using these comments only when any module is uninstalled and if only a single module is overriding the module then the file gets deleted.